# Linking Number and Intersection Number

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for simplicity).  If a closed curve $\gamma$ is linked with $\partial \Sigma$ with linking number $n$ (mod 2) then $\gamma$ should (generically) intersect $\Sigma$ in $n$ points (mod 2).  What is the right topological machinery one needs to prove this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is homology theory and Poincare duality! Also as a comment, the intersection number exactly equals the linking number if you count intersections with appropriate sign.

Let $L=L_1\cup L_2$ be a link of two components. Then consider $L_1$ as a homology class inside $H_1(\mathbb R^3\setminus L_2)\cong \mathbb Z$. This integer is the linking number. This is essentially equivalent to the definition you give in terms of intersection number. This is because $H_2(\mathbb R^3\setminus n(L_2),\partial n(L_2))\cong \mathbb Z$, and there is a bilinear pairing 
$$H_1(\mathbb R^3\setminus L_2)\otimes H_2(\mathbb R^3\setminus n(L_2),\partial n(L_2))\to\mathbb Z$$ given by intersection number. In particular, a meridian to $L_2$ intersects a surface $\Sigma$ bounding $L_2$ in a point, so that a way to read off how many multiples of the meridian you are homologous to is to check your intersection number with $\Sigma$. Here $n(L_2)$ is a tubular neighborhood of $L_2$ with torus boundary. (The intersection pairing is closely related to Poincare duality, to answer your original question of what machinery is necessary to prove this.)

The next question is why the class of $L_1$ inside $H_1(\mathbb R^3\setminus L_2)$ equals the linking number. One way to see this is that you can disentangle $L_1$ from $L_2$ by doing crossing changes, which correspond to adding or subtracting multiples of the meridian to the homology class represented by $L_1$. This is equivalent, if you think about it a bit, to the usual definition of linking number as counting crossings with sign. I leave the details to you.

Comment: I can't resist mentioning yet another interpretation of linking number. First work in $S^3$ rather than $\mathbb R^3$ for convenience. Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ bound immersed disks $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ in the $4$-ball $B^4$. These two disks generically intersect in points. The linking number is the algebraic intersection number between these two disks. This way of defining linking number is more symmetric than interpreting one component in the homology of the complement of the other.

Comment: I'm interested in this last interpretation of the linking number. Can I find a longer treatment of it (possibly with a proof that the definition is equivalent to one of the other definitions of linking) in a book?

Comment: @schneeewittchen I'm not sure where you can find a written treatment. I would check some books on 4-manifold topology. Maybe Scorpan's book? (The Wild World of 4-Manifolds)

Comment: @schneeewittchen: Looks like I remembered correctly. See pp.145-147 of "The Wild World of 4-manifolds" by Scorpan.

Comment: How about the fact that linking numbers in many 3-manifolds are not always defined or limited to integers? --Ken Perko

Comment: @user43408 I don't quite understand your remark. The question was not about general 3-manifolds.